# Login success when giving wrong username and password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

Here is my code and it gives login success even after just clicking on submit button.

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);
 //sql dtabase conn
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
    //query the dtabase for user

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users where username = 
    '$username' and password = '$password'")or die("failed to query database".mysqli_connect_error());

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);

    if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password && ("" 
    !== $username || "" !== $password)){
        echo "Login success".$row['username'];
    }else{
        echo "Failed to login";
    }
```

I am a beginner at this. Please help me out

Comment: Don't use isset to assign on variables. Use some escape function or something. You should place the isset on an if statement

Comment: First of all fix this line two line `$username = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username']: "";
$password = isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password']:"";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `isset` to check the username / password post payload. This returns a `true` / `false`, not a value. So you'll never match a record in the DB and you'll never match the conditions of you credentials check (either a match or `""`)

Try something like

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
```

Which will set `$username` equal to the `$_POST['username']` value OR to `false` if it's not set. Then you can test for it with something like:

```
if (($username && $password) and ($username == $row['username'] and $password == $row['password']))
```

Which should get you a lot closer than you are.

One other point-- you need to use some sort of hashing mechanism for the password. The way you've got it it looks like you're searching for a plaintext password value (unless you're hashing on the front end, I guess). Never store passwords in the DB as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Your last condition in your IF statement || is true, the password is not empty because your isset() will always return a value and it will always be a success.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//sql dtabase conn
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
//query the dtabase for user

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users where username = 
'$username' and password = '$password'")or die("failed to query database".mysqli_connect_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);

if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    echo "Login success".$row['username'];
}else{
    echo "Failed to login";
}
```